Selenium how to find button that is part of a 'flex flex-col md:grid class
Using Selenium in Python, I want to click on a button with text 'View Active', but Selenium can't find it when searching for 'View Active'.  Looking at the code with 'inspect' (see below), I see the following for the 'flex-col' class containing the button.  I can see the button text, but I don't know how to access it from Selenium.
<div class="flex flex-col md:grid md:grid-cols-2 mt-7 flex-wrap gap-x-7 gap-y-7">
  <div class="bg-white shadow-chart px-8 py-6  w-full">
    <h4 class="font-bold">Moved from Registered Address</h4>
    <p class="mt-1 mb-6">Review for consideration of challenge</p>
    <div class="flex gap-3 flex-col md:flex-row">
      <a class=" px-2 py-3 rounded-lg text-base hover:shadow-btn disabled:opacity-30 outline-none focus:ring-red focus:ring-2 w-44 bg-red text-white block text-center" href="/assignedVoters">View All</a>
      <a class=" px-2 py-3 rounded-lg text-base hover:shadow-btn disabled:opacity-30 outline-none focus:ring-red focus:ring-2 w-44 bg-red text-white block text-center" href="/assignedVoters?activeOnly=true">View Active</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-white shadow-chart px-8 py-6  w-full">
    <h4 class="font-bold">Non-Standard Addresses</h4>
    <p class="mt-1 mb-6">Sorted by largest # of registrations</p>
    <div class="flex gap-3 flex-col md:flex-row">
      <a class=" px-2 py-3 rounded-lg text-base hover:shadow-btn disabled:opacity-30 outline-none focus:ring-red focus:ring-2 w-44 bg-red text-white block text-center" href="/addressWithIssues">View All</a>
      <a class=" px-2 py-3 rounded-lg text-base hover:shadow-btn disabled:opacity-30 outline-none focus:ring-red focus:ring-2 w-44 bg-red text-white block text-center" href="/addressWithIssues?activeOnly=true">View Active</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-white shadow-chart px-8 py-6  w-full">
    <h4 class="font-bold">Search by Name</h4>
    <p class="mt-1 mb-6">Search for records by voter name</p>
    <div class="flex gap-3 flex-col md:flex-row">
      <a class=" px-2 py-3 rounded-lg text-base hover:shadow-btn disabled:opacity-30 outline-none focus:ring-red focus:ring-2 w-44 bg-red text-white block text-center" href="/search/name">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-white shadow-chart px-8 py-6  w-full">
    <h4 class="font-bold">Search by Address</h4>
    <p class="mt-1 mb-6">Search for records by address</p>
    <div class="flex gap-3 flex-col md:flex-row">
      <a class=" px-2 py-3 rounded-lg text-base hover:shadow-btn disabled:opacity-30 outline-none focus:ring-red focus:ring-2 w-44 bg-red text-white block text-center" href="/search/address">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-white shadow-chart px-8 py-6  w-full">
    <h4 class="font-bold">My Challenges</h4>
    <p class="mt-1 mb-6">Review records selected for challenge</p>
    <div class="flex gap-3 flex-col md:flex-row">
      <a class=" px-2 py-3 rounded-lg text-base hover:shadow-btn disabled:opacity-30 outline-none focus:ring-red focus:ring-2 w-44 bg-red text-white block text-center" href="/reviewChallenges">View Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Here is the python code I am using (for obvious reasons I deleted my password)
from re import L
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

cService = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Frank\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2022\\Projects\\IV3_WebsiteAutomation\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = cService)
driver.get("https://app.iv3.us/login")
print(driver.title)

search_bar = driver.find_element("name", "userName")
search_bar.send_keys("paynterf@gmail.com")
search_bar = driver.find_element("name", "password")
search_bar.send_keys("-----------------")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

res = driver.find_element(By.XPATH(".//a[contains(@href,'View Active')]"))

driver.close() 

This code properly opens the web page and enters the username and password.  The next page that opens contains the 'View Active' button I am trying to activate

please see my answer below it outlines how to use relative Xpath for getting all buttons(a href links) from a containing class name and how to click them. if you found my answer helpful please mark it as the correct answer.

seems you changed your question after the fact, I deleted mine. Sikora's answer is the correct answer.

You can use By.LINK_TEXT to find it. Since there are 2 links that can be picked, you can select which one you are interested in.
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'View Active')[0] # or [1]
element.click()


Close, but not quite:

Close, but not quite:  When I ran it, I got the error 'list' object has no attribute 'click'. Also, "element = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'View Active')[0] # or [1]" doesn't work (produces 'out of range index' error), but "element = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'View Active') #w/o index" does

tried  res = driver.find_element(By.XPATH(".//a[contains(@href,'View Active')]")), but this returns the error "'str' object is not callable".  this looks like a python error, but I have no idea how to fix it

I edited my original question to show the python code I am using.

for reference you need to understand driver.find_elements returns a list you need to loop through.
if you use driver.find_element (without the s) you will get an error if there is more than one element. you need to pop the code into a loop and then you should get a click value.

To find the link containing the text, "View Active", we can use a simple XPath
//a[text()='View Active']

The problem on this page is that link is not unique... it finds two. So we need to specify which link to select... I chose to do this based on the H4 text above,
//div[./h4[text()='Non-Standard Addresses']]//a[text()='View Active']

or we can choose the other one using
//div[./h4[text()='Moved from Registered Address']]//a[text()='View Active']

I like this method over the other current answers because it makes it clear which one you are targeting based on the clearly visible heading text.

Adding to Sikora's answer. find_elements returns a list of objects. despite it having an index associated its better practice to loop through it.
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

elements = driver.find_elements(By.LINK_TEXT, 'View Active')
for element in elements: 
    element.click()

OR find_element which returns the first item found and if no element has a matching id attribute, a NoSuchElementException will be raised.
element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'View Active')
element.click()

